# How to make dialogue box in apple script to wait until user gives in put

Tags: macos, applescript-objc

I am trying to get a dialogue box in mac using apple script.

```
    tell application "System Events"
    activate
    display dialog "Enter your name:  " default answer "" buttons {"OK"}   default button "OK" with title "Good Name"
    set the Name to text returned of the result
```

The problem i am facing is, when i don't enter name, the popup is closing by itself throwing error. But i want it to stay alive till user gives input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to add a `repeat` that which acts on the error:

```
set theMessage to ""
set theIcon to note

tell application "System Events"
    activate
    repeat
        display dialog theMessage & "Enter your name:  " default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button "OK" cancel button "Cancel" with title "Good Name" with icon theIcon
        set the theName to text returned of the result
        try
            if theName = "" then error
            exit repeat
        on error
            set theMessage to "Invalid. "
            set theIcon to caution
        end try
    end repeat
    display dialog "Your name is " & theName & "." buttons {"OK"} default button "OK" with icon note
end tell
```

When input is "" within the repeat `on error` is triggered, which gives an `invalid` message and repeats the input dialog — otherwise the script continues (name output added as example).